# Excel Nested Formulas Error

Tags: search, nested, excel-formula, countif

In excel I have a Pivot Table with several calculated fields, my nested statement is this...

```
=(D54)/COUNTIF(B:B,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total",B54,1)),LEFT(B54,SEARCH("Total",B54,1)-2)))
```

If returns the correct answer on the SUM of my column but i want it to return nothing or "" when it is not a sum field.  Instead it returns this...

```
7.37961E-05
```

I've tried adding the "" to the False portion of the IF statement and it returns a #DIV/o! error.

Comment: what do you have in D54, and in other columns? how is it all organized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting 7.37961E-05, but assuming you have something like "123 Total" in B54 you need to take the IF statement outside the rest of the formula and test for the presence of the string "Total" in B54 first:-

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Total",B54,1)),(D54)/COUNTIF(B:B,LEFT(B54,SEARCH("Total",B54,1)-2)),"")
```

It can still give a #DIV/0! error if nothing in column B matches the number you are searching for.